# Include image in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm trying to include user image in `ListView`. How can I include image in this list view. Please help me to solve this.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvwUsers" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>

              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h3><%# Eval("UserName") %></h3>

                    <p><%# Eval("Email") %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <i class="ion ion-person-add" ></i>
                </div>

              </div>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this one method:

image path:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <img src='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' alt="" />
                </ItemTemplate>
```

And other codes

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" >
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div>
                    <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>' alt="" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Right, you're on the right track. This should do the trick:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID='Image1' runat='server' ImageUrl='~/assets/Image/?id=<%#Eval("AlbumID") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save image path in DB and render it in `<img>` Tag

```
          <!-- small box -->
          <div class="small-box bg-aqua">
            <div class="inner">

             <img src='<%# Eval("Image_url") %>"/>

              <h3><%# Eval("UserName") %></h3>

                <p><%# Eval("Email") %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-person-add" ></i>
            </div>

          </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```